# Virtual Audio Cable equivalent for OS X

Tags: macos, mac, audio, operating-systems, system-sounds

I have been astounded by the lack of programs for OS X that have similar functionality to Virtual Audio Cable. My goal is to "redirect" audio output to auto input.

I realize that OS X's and Windows' implementation of sound IO are fundamentally different, but I am willing to settle for something like only being able to redirect all system sound. Is this possible, or am I better off just virtualizing?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Ahh thank you, I was wondering if this would be off topic but my hurried mind felt that SU would be like a general version of SO and did not look into any specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe pro audio apps use CoreAudio *Audio Units* or Steinberg *Virtual Studio Technology* (VST) plug-ins to do this (and more).

To do similar things with apps that don't have AU or VST support, see [Rogue Amoeba](https://rogueamoeba.com)'s [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) or [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/), or [Ambrosia Software](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/)'s [WireTap Studio](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wiretap/) or [WireTap Anywhere](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wta/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Loopback works perfectly and, for my uses, is superior in every way to Virtual Audio Cable.